# Multiple Sources in Single GraphQL query (Gatsby)

Tags: json, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I'm new to GraphQL and Gatsby and looking to understand programmatic approach to "joining" data from two different sources in my Gatsby project. I have an albums.json file that I am querying as follows:

```
query MyQuery {
  allAlbumsJson(sort: {fields: releaseDate, order: DESC}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        slug
        releaseDate
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a markdown file for each album whose path is dynamically generated. How can I pull in fields from my markdown files into the above query based on, say, the title field, which is part of the frontmatter for the markdown?

If I have to make explicit connections between the nodes generated by the gatsby-transformer-json plugin and the ones generated by the gatsby-transformer-remark plugin, how and where would I do that? I've been looking at similar questions but still am stumped as to the most efficient way to do this. Thanks for your help!